Unable to achieve tree table in reactjs with connecting lines

Hi, I am trying to achieve following design using tailwindcss and reactjs but not able to. I am able to do recursive render but not able to create connecting lines.
I was able to do so using ul/li but my requirement is for table.
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/d32t7n8p/3/
<ul>
<li><div>Level 1</div></li>
<li><div>Level 1</div>
    <ul>
        <li><div>Level 2</div></li>
        <li><div>Level 2</div>
            <ul>
                <li><div>Level 3</div></li>
                <li><div>Level 3</div></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><div>Level 1</div></li>
</ul>

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

li div {
 padding-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

li div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 0.75em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 0 none transparent;
  border-right: 0 none transparent;
}

ul li:last-child > div::before {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 4px; /* Round the bottom-left corner */
}

ul > li:last-child {
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
}


Can you provide the html structure of your table ? Why using table when ul/li is more convenient IMO ?
